# Not able to pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table  User

```
Field            FieldValue SyUserid
Full Name          Sohan        338
Full Name         Krishnan      378
Total Experience    2 to 5 years    338
Total Experience    2 to 5 years    378
Userid  338 338
Userid  378 378
```

I want the data in the format

```
syuserid    Full Name   Total Experience    userid
338 NULL    NULL    NULL
378 NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I tried to use this qry in sql server 2008 DB but the values are appearing as NULL

```
SELECT *
FROM #User
PIVOT (MAX(Field) 
       FOR FieldValue in ([Full Name],[Total Experience],[Userid])) AS pvt
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Flip field and fieldvalue

Comment: Thanks Rabbit...thanks fr the quick help